# Java - Eclipse plugin - populate a tree item with a table

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, widget, swt

I have 2 Java beans Classes - Company and Employee. Employee.java has the attributes "name"(String), "email" (String) and "salary"(int), and getters and setters for all attributes. Company.java has attributes "name" (String), "city" (String) and "employees" (List), getters and setters.
I want to create TreeTable which contains the list of companies, and for each company, I want to display, as TreeItem, a table with the list of employees for the company. For this implementation I am using classes from org.eclipse.swt.widgets.
This is my code for TreeTable:

```
public class CompaniesTableCreation {

private static List<Company> companies;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Tree companiesTree = new Tree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    companiesTree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(companiesTree, SWT.LEFT);
    column1.setText("Name");
    column1.setWidth(200);
    TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(companiesTree, SWT.LEFT);
    column2.setText("City");
    column2.setWidth(200);
    for (Company c : companies) {
        TreeItem companyTreeItem = new TreeItem(companiesTree, SWT.NONE);
        companyTreeItem.setText(new String[] { c.getName(), c.getCity() });
        
        Table employeesTable = new Table(companiesTree, SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        employeesTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
        String[] titles = { "Name", "Email address", "Salary" };

        for (String title : titles) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(employeesTable, SWT.NULL);
            column.setText(title);
        }

        for (Employee e : c.getEmployees()) {
            TableItem employeeTableItem = new TableItem(employeesTable,
                    SWT.NULL);
            employeeTableItem.setText(0, e.getName());
            employeeTableItem.setText(1, e.getEmail());
            employeeTableItem.setText(2, String.valueOf(e.getSalary()));
        }

        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < titles.length; loopIndex++) {
            employeesTable.getColumn(loopIndex).pack();
        }
        
        TreeItem employeesItem = new TreeItem(companyTreeItem, SWT.NONE);
        employeesItem.setData(employeesTable);          

        //  If I display the employees as simple TableItems, data is OK, but I need a Table
        /*for (Employee e : c.getEmployees()) {
            TreeItem employeeItem = new TreeItem(treeItem, SWT.NONE);
            employeeItem.setText(new String[] { e.getName(),
                    e.getEmail(),String.valueOf(e.getSalary()) });

        }*/
    }
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

private static void init()
{
    companies = new ArrayList<Company>();
    Company c = new Company("IBM", "New York");
    c.addEmployee(new Employee("John", "john.ibm.com", 100));
    c.addEmployee(new Employee("Michael", "michael.ibm.com", 200));
    companies.add(c);
    
    c = new Company("Google", "San Francicsco");
    c.addEmployee(new Employee("Linda", "linda.google.com", 100));
    c.addEmployee(new Employee("Harry", "harry.google.com", 150));
    c.addEmployee(new Employee("Tom", "tom.google.com", 120));
    companies.add(c);
}
}
```

The expected result is when I expand a company from the Tree, to open the Table with employees assigned to this company, but in the current implementation, nothing happens.

Comment: I'm not sure that nesting Tables in a Tree works, I don't recall ever seeing code like that. You would normally just use multiple TreeItems as children of the top level TreeItems. Note that if you are doing an Eclipse plug-in the JFace `TreeViewer` is usually easier to use.

Comment: I am trying to do this. If I'll have some questions, I'll post.